# The usage of any in affirmative sentences with countable nouns

Tags: grammatical-number

I want to know whether the following sentence is correct:

> Revoking or invoking any new laws(or law?) can affect a large number of people's lives.

My tutor told me that *"any"* in positive sentences should be accompanied by a singular form even if the noun is countable.

Comment: Perhaps you will want to try https://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: The combination ***revoking** or **invoking*** strikes me as something of a "zeugma". Ordinarily, only parliament/lawmakers can ***revoke*** (do away with, repeal) a law, whereas ***invoking*** a law is usually something an aggrieved person does to obtain justice (it's about *using* the law, not *passing/repealing* laws). Structurally, I expect *X-ing or Y-ing something* in OP's context to involve true "opposites" (such as ***passing** or **repealing** new laws*), but that doesn't work in the cited example.

Comment: "The first thing to remember is that we only use some and any directly before either a plural noun or an uncountable noun." Read more here (https://dictionaryblog.cambridge.org/2017/01/18/some-or-any-little-words-that-cause-big-problems/)